# How do I capture and store a user's fingerprint within my android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, fingerprint, android-api-levels

I am trying to use the fingerprint sensor in an android device to capture and store a user's fingerprint within my android app. Is there a fingerprint api available for this? The Google fingerprint API i found only takes care of authenticating a user and for making payments. Please help!!! Your suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that would be available; imagine the implications for rouge apps; capture user's fingerprints and share that information!  Like asking for a blood sample.

Comment: @Mark Stewart, thank you for your contributions, I'm still on the look out though.